# How to select more than one radio button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to create students attendance class base using javascript in laravel 8 so javascript search and  show successfully all students from specific class but I couldn't select more than one radio button so what can I do?

Comment: That is the Whole Point of a radio button. You can select only one. So if you want to select more, you will have to change to using a set of checkbox's

Comment: I know we can only select once choice from radio button but I explained I wanna make students attendance class base, every class teacher search their class and take attendance and for attendance is not good to use from checkbox

Answer (score 3):

the difference between checkboxes and radio buttons:

- checkboxes are used when the user can select one or more options,
- radio buttons are used when the user can choose only one of two or more options.

You are probably needing to change your radio buttons to checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you can: [Radio buttons selecting multiple options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442044/radio-buttons-selecting-multiple-options). But you can use checkboxes are used when you can select one or more options